# OpenCV c++ Assertion

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been struggling with some assertion in opencv project.

First I'm converting Mat objects to be sure about their types:

```
gray_im.convertTo(gray_im, CV_8U);
diff_im.convertTo(diff_im, CV_8U);
```

Then I do a subtraction. This line is where I got the assertion:

```
diff_im = gray_im - prev_im;
```

And here is the assertion:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified) in arithm_op, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 1313
```

When I print info about images I'm using in subtraction;

```
diff_im. type: 5 rows: 600 cols 800 
gray_im. type: 5 rows: 600 cols 800 
prev_im. type: 0 rows: 600 cols 800
```

I think that I'm explicitly specifying output array (and if I'm correct, here diff_im is output array, right?) by converting it to CV_8U. Also when I print the type information of diff_im in runtime, it says it is "5" which means that I have explicitly specified the type of "diff_im".

Am I wrong here? Any suggestions?

OpenCV version: 2.4.8
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gray_im` has type 5 and `prev_im` has type 0. You may forgot to initialize `prev_im` correctly, i.e.:

```
prev_im = cv::Mat::zeros(gray_im.size(), gray_im.type());
```

---

**Update #1:**

Well, `dst = src1 - src2` is equivalent to `subtract(dst, src1, dst)`. The parameter `dst` is `OutputArray` and used for output function parameter only. The type of `dst` cannot be defined by `operator-` only `subtract()` provides possibility for that by its parameter `dtype`, see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#subtract).

If `dtype` is not given and both of the input parameters are arrays then `src1.type()` must be equal to `src2.type()`, see [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp#L654).

So you should overwrite `operator-` as below:

```
cv::Mat src1(600, 800, CV_8U);
cv::Mat src2(600, 800, CV_32F);
cv::Mat dst;

//dst = src1 - src2; // --> this will give the same assert
cv::subtract(src1, src2, dst, cv::noArray(), CV_32F); // type of dst is CV_32F
```

Comment: However the assertion says **When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified**, which means (I think) **I can handle different type of inputs, but in this case you must specify the type that I'll write.**. And If I'm correct, in this case the output is diff_im, and it's type explicitly specified (which is 5 in this example). Right?

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Will let you know the result by the end of this day. And additionally, is there any reason of changing the image type unintendedly?

Comment: no, there isn't any reason, it will work with `dtype=CV_8U`, but I wasn't sure  whether `subtract` handles overflow or not

Comment: sorry for late reply. seems to resolved problem. thanks in advance.